# plink in PowerShell to run commands on Linux machine (SuSE)

Tags: linux, powershell-3.0, putty, plink

I am trying to automate the process of adding extra storage in a linux machine. I'm using `plink` in PowerShell installed on my Windows machine.

Below is the code:

```
$plinkpath = "C:\Users\mydrive\Modules\plink.exe"
if (Test-Path $plinkpath) {
    Set-Alias plink $plinkpath
} else {
    throw "Plink.exe is reqruied"
}
$passw = "linuxadmin$123"
$commands = @(
    "sudo su;",
    "pvcreate /dev/sde;",
    "vgcreate test_vog /dev/sde",
    "lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n test_lev test_vog;",
    "mkfs.ext3 /dev/test_vog/test_lev;",
    "mkdir /azurenew;",
    "echo ""/dev/test_vog/test_lev /azurenew/ ext3 defaults 1 1"" >> /etc/fstab;",
    "mount /azurenew/;" 
)
```

**Approach 1: Using .ppk file**

```
plink -ssh -i "C:\Users\amurthy\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\sshprivate.ppk" linuxadmin@xx.xx.xx.xxx $commands
```

In the above situation PowerShell hangs and no response on the console. Not sure what's happening.

**Approach 2: using direct log in**

```
plink -P "22" -v "linuxadmin@xx.xx.xx.xxx" -pw "linuxadmin$123" $commands
```

Here, I get below response on console

Using username "linuxadmin".
Sent password
**Password authentication failed**

I do not understand why the passoword authentication failed though I am able to login using putty.exe with that password.

Can anyone please help me here to solve my above automation problem? If you have any better solution altogether really welcome.

Comment: What happens, when you run `plink -ssh -i ...` on command-line?

Answer (score 0):

The password login attempt fails because you defined the password in a double-quoted string. PowerShell tries to expand the (undefined) variable `$123` in `linuxadmin$123`, so you're actually passing just `linuxadmin` as the password. You could use a single-quoted string to avoid this, but public key authentication (your first approach) is the better approach anyway, so I recommend sticking with that.

I'm not sure why your first approach causes the console to hang, though. If the key were password-protected you should be prompted for the password. There's a semicolon missing at the end of `"vgcreate test_vog /dev/sde"`, but if that caused an issue I'd expect to see an error message.

Try running `plink` with the parameter `-v` (verbose messages) to get a better picture of what's going on.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, thx a lot it really worked. But the problem is that, i am loggin in as linuxadmin user but i need super user access to run those commands. below is the verbose and i tried to find the solution for that but couldn't. appreciate if you could helpme here                              
 Using username "linuxadmin".
Sent password
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Started a shell/command
Server sent command exit status 127
bash: fdisk: command not found
Disconnected: All channels closed

Comment: and below is the complete command run verbose Using username "linuxadmin".
Sent password
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Started a shell/command
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
bash: pvcreate: command not found
bash: vgcreate: command not found
bash: mkfs.ext3: command not found
mkdir: 
cannot create directory â€˜/azurenewâ€™
: Permission denied
bash: /etc/fstab: Permission denied
mount: 
/azurenew/
: 
No such file or directory
Server sent command exit status 1
Disconnected: All channels closed

Comment: remove `sudo su` and prefix all commands that require root privileges with `sudo` (`$commands = "sudo pvcreate ...;", "sudo vgcreate ...;", ...`).

Comment: Thanks ansgar. But still it did not run. But plink -ssh -pw 'pass1' -t linuxadmin@xx.xx.xx.xxx echo linuxadmin_123 | sudo -S ls" is enabling to to login as sudo user. am trying to run multiple commands

Comment: Change the `sudo` configuration to allow the user `linuxadmin` to run the commands [without being prompted for a password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password).